# scanf not working in a while loop

Tags: c, file, while-loop

I was trying to enter a few numbers into a file, and hence created a while loop. After entering a value, i ask the user if he wishes to repeat the process. However, the program  just prints the second printf statement and the while loop terminates. The program is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("numbers.txt", "w");
    int a;
    char ch = 'y';
    while(ch == 'y')
    {
        printf("Enter the number\n");
        scanf("%d", &a);
        fprintf(fp, "%d", a);
        printf("Do you want to continue?");
        scanf("%c", &ch);                           //doesn't work at all
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Why doesn't the second scanf work?

Comment: `scanf("%c", &ch); ` --> `scanf(" %c", &ch); `  someone please find a dupe.

Answer (score 6):

That is because there is a left over newline character in the input buffer.

You can consume that by giving a space before `%c` in `scanf()`

```
scanf(" %c", &ch);
```

---

As a side note

1) Please use the standard definition of `main()` for no command-line parameters

```
int main(void)
```

2) Check the return value of `fopen()`, `scanf()` and other function calls.

Answer (score 1):

```
scanf("%c", &ch);
```

should be

```
scanf(" %c", &ch);
```

Note the space before `%c`. There is a newline character while scanning integer(a) which is picked up by `%c` so you need to get rid of it using a space.